# QGIS forms : field display based on the value of another field

Tags: qgis, forms

I have a form designed in QGIS 3.8.1. The form is associated with a layer for inputting data. Many of the fields on the form are only relevant if the first field is equal to True.

Example:

Field 1: Is the location positive for mosquito larvae? True/False

Field 2: What stage are the larvae at? L1, L2, L3, Pupae

I do not want Field 2 to be shown unless the value in Field 1 is equal to True. How can I achieve that the Field 2 is displayed only when Field 1 is equal to True?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS SE. It would help if you provided what you did so far (your code/script) and you could provide some example data, so we can replicate your problem and try to find a solution.

Comment: A similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/386018/35561

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this through the Attributes Form in the Layers properties. Choose Drag and drop designer. Drag and drop your attributes from Available Widgets-window into the Form Layout-window.

Set alias and widget type. Here I have chosen checkbox where 1 ("pos_loc") is True and 0 is False for field 1 and value map for field 2 ("stage").
[image: pos_loc parameters]
[image: stage parameters]

Add a tab/container (the green plus). The first time you must choose tab and then afterwards change it to a group (container). Give it a name and click OK.

A new tab is added.

[image]

Click on "stage" and drag it into and drop it in "Larvae stage"

[image]

Double right-click on Larvae stage and check 'Show as group box' and 'Control visibility by expression' and add the expression `"pos_loc"=1` and click OK.

[image]

Close layer properties. Activate the layer and start editing. A pop-up window like this appears.

[image]

If I check the box (the location is positive), the stage field turns up and I can choose a stage from the drop down list.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for this! Don't suppose you can answer my other question on how to get my Qfield project off the mobile device and into QGis?

Comment: Glad I could help. I create my project in QGIS, then I use QFieldSync plugin to make it portable, then I copy the project into my tablet, use it and when finished, I copy my project back on the PC. (I use a regular USB-B or -C cabel to connect my tablet to the PC.) Read more on https://qfield.org/docs/index.html.