# Container 'Control visibility by expression' for relations

Tags: qgis, expression, relates, visibility, attribute-form

I have two relations in a project on QGIS 3.10. They have the same field ('fid') of the parent but different fields ('topo_part';'topo_part_loc') of the same child. I want to see these relations in the attribute form of the layer parent. Actually, I want to see only the relation that relate some geometry childs because one relation keeps out the other one.
[image]
So I've made two container in the Drag and Drop Designer. Each of them contains a different relation of the layer. Now, i'm looking for an expression to control visibility.
[image]
I've tried many expressions but none of them work.
[image]
Where is the mistake? Any other solution?

Comment: maybe check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332621/qgis-forms-field-display-based-on-the-value-of-another-field